# What can be done for my three year old, male, neutered cat based on the info below?

Tags: cats, health

My vet just saw one of my cats this morning and he had a temp of 106+ degrees.  He sounds very congested when he coughs, which is seldom.  There is no runny nose or sneezing.  Without further testing and x-rays, he says it could be the herpes virus or his heart.  What can you tell me?

Comment: This is a question for your veterinarian, not for the internet. You should speak to your vet about what steps to take next.

Comment: It's one of those things that needs to have diagnostics ran in order to further help your animal. 106 is REALLY high for a cat.

Comment: I know 106+ is very high.  just took it here at home and it is down to 105.7. he's eating canned food to which I'm adding a little water and he peed good in the litter box.  acts like he feels a bit better.  we offered him treats and he loves them - ate at least 12-14.  want to keep his appetite up.  his vet said he has ear mites - have you ever heard of Mineral Oil to treat ear mites?  we think the ear mites came from the feral kittens we rescued a month ago.  i rescue and have to stop.... just can do it anymore after 40 years.  thank you for responding to my question.

Comment: Seek urgent veterinary care for you cat. Please let us know how you get on.